# Select the parent of a element

Tags: css, menu, highlight

I try to highlight the "mother" menu item

here is the CSS

```
.current-menu-item {
 background-color: red;
 background-image: none;
}
```

it work for the menu item, but I don't want the precise item, just the mother

menu example

- menu one
- - menu two
- - menu three

two and three child menu of one... I like to highlight one on ANY selection two or three

Comment: `.current-menu-item:first-child` this should work.

Comment: @Mr_Green that won't work because he want to select the "parent element" when, for example, the user hover or focus in any child element. With :first-child you only select the child elements but not the parents.

Comment: @leoMestizo yeah I wasn't clear..

Comment: What do you want to do menardmam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't able to select the parent element of a element.

The follow selector don't exists in CSS... Yet:

```
:parent /* DON'T EXISTS! */
```

**You only can do that with JavaScript.**

Comment: and what about .current-menu-item < a

Comment: @menardmam I think, that is in less or sass. but not in pure css.